# Why is Container.Configure taking so long?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

Today I was investigating slowness in our system.  By inserting some debug logs, I narrowed it down to this segment:

```
var db = MyDbContext.ForShard(shardKey);
_logger.Debug("Point 1");
container.Configure(cfg =>
                    {
                        _logger.Debug("Anon 1");
                        cfg.For<MyDbContext>().Use(db);
                        _logger.Debug("Anon 2");
                    });
_logger.Debug("Point 2");
```

The database is sharded, and `shardKey` identifies which shard to use.  The call to `MyDbContext.ForShard()` returns a database connection whose connection string refers to the correct shard.  The snippet in question then tells the StructureMap `Container` to use this instance for dependency injection.

In the logs, the time lag between each line is negligible, except for the gap between "Anon 2" and "Point 2", which can take in the region of a second.  Not good.  But I've never seen StructureMap taking so long to configure a usage.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Setting up a container take time. For a big application many seconds is no exception. Why is this delay of 1 second a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by the nice folks from StructureMap on their [GitHub](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/issues/505) page:

> @CoreyKaylor says: The configure call shouldn't happen during runtime, only startup so if this call is happening for every web request as an example it would be extremely slow as the configure call requires a global lock. A better alternative if you absolutely need runtime overrides is to use a nested container for the scope of an http request and pass TypeArguments to the nested container. That's all assuming you're running the latest version of StructureMap too.

In my case this translates to:

```
var db = MyDbContext.ForShard(shardKey);
var typeArgs = new TypeArguments();
typeArgs[typeof(MyDbContext)] = db;
var nested = container.GetNestedContainer(typeArgs);
```